# aws xray: Missing sql query and django user in traces

Tags: aws-xray

I do get traces, and the traces do not contain the query as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-segmentdocuments.html#api-segmentdocuments-sql)

only:

`"sql": {
"database_type": "mysql",
"user": "******" 
}`

Do I need to add anything in RDS to allow for this to work?

in the django settings? somewhere else?

I'm also missing the actual user, ( I do get the correct user Ip and browser agent, but not the authenticated user)

Using the official python sdk with the django middleware and the following stack:

Django 1.11
xray 2.1.0
Daemon 3
Connected to RDS mysql db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X-Ray SDKs don't support the query capture unless there is a reliable way to log the parameterized ones. For Python SDK only SQLAlchemy supports such capture. You can see the full response in the AWS X-Ray forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=290748&tstart=0.